# Активные сессии пользователя

Tags: java, wicket

Необходимо получить все сессии активного пользователя (IP, браузер...). Текущую сессию получаю обычным образом: `AuthenticatedWebSession.get()`.

Есть ли в Wicket какой-то стандартный способ для получения всех сессий с дальнейшей возможностью выбрать из них сессии текущего пользователя? Или все таки единственный вариант - сохранять в базе данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте повесить слушателя сессий, типа:

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

  private static AtomicInteger totalSessions;

  public static int getTotalSession(){
    return totalSessions.get();
  }

  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    totalSessions.getAndIncrement();
 }

  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    totalSessions.decrementAndGet();
  } 
}
```

Слушателя надо декларировать в web.xml